# Create table and then insert data into the new table from another table

Tags: plsql

I am creating one table name emp_inforamtion with checking that table is exist in database or not ,and if not then creating table then inserting the data from bank table in to emp_information table.

```
DECLARE
  ncount NUMBER;
  v_sql  VARCHAR2(4000);
  CURSOR c1
  IS
    SELECT bank_code,
      center_code,
      bank_name,
      logo
    FROM bank
    WHERE bank_code ='607143';
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(1) INTO ncount FROM tab WHERE tname LIKE '%EMP_INFORMATION%';
  IF (ncount <= 0) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (ncount || 'count');
    BEGIN
      v_sql :=' CREATE TABLE EMP_INFORMATION  
(    
emp_id         VARCHAR2(3),    
emp_name       VARCHAR2(20),    
emp_salary     VARCHAR2(3),    
emp_department VARCHAR2(3)  
)';
      EXECUTE immediate v_sql;
      COMMIT;
      BEGIN
        FOR i IN c1
        LOOP
          INSERT
          INTO EMP_INFORMATION
            (
              emp_id,
              emp_name,
              emp_salary,
              emp_department
            )
            VALUES
            (
              i.bank_code,
              i.bank_name,
              i.center_code,
              i.logo
            );
        END LOOP;
      END;
    END;
  END IF;
  end;
/
```

found below error after executing the above cursor:

> ORA-06550: line 30, column 16: PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   ORA-06550: line 29, column 11: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: Where do you check for existence? Look in your line 30, column 16 which table you try to access; we don't have any line numbers here.

Comment: I just gave you some hints.

Comment: appreciate for your response.

Comment: Line 30 at INTO EMP_INFORMATION...statement,column 16 start with EMP_INFORMATION

Comment: i think table was not created and when it wad trying to insert data into that table its gives error saying table or view does not exist...is it?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a table using execute immediate in an anonymous block, use execute immediate to insert the data into it.

```
DECLARE
  ncount NUMBER;
  v_sql  VARCHAR2(4000);
  CURSOR c1
  IS
    SELECT bank_code,
      center_code,
      bank_name,
      logo
    FROM bank
    WHERE bank_code ='607143';
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(1) INTO ncount FROM tab WHERE tname LIKE '%EMP_INFORMATION%';
  IF (ncount <= 0) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (ncount || 'count');
    BEGIN
      v_sql :=' CREATE TABLE EMP_INFORMATION  
                (    
                  emp_id         VARCHAR2(3),    
                  emp_name       VARCHAR2(20),    
                  emp_salary     VARCHAR2(3),    
                  emp_department VARCHAR2(3)  
                )';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
      BEGIN
        FOR i IN c1
        LOOP
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT
          INTO EMP_INFORMATION
            (
              emp_id,
              emp_name,
              emp_salary,
              emp_department
            )
            VALUES
            (
              :a,
              :b,
              :c,
              :d
            )' using i.bank_code, i.bank_name, i.center_code, i.logo;
        END LOOP;
      END;
    END;
  END IF;
  end;
/
```